# I dont want the toggle functionality when the target is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a step by step order, and I'm using *data-id="x"* to tell which content to be visible when it has been selected.

What I am trying to accomplish is if the **data-id** has the same target the toggle will not take function, but simply the other div clicked would be selected instead.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
$('li').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // remove selected class from links after the current one
  $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('li').removeClass('selected');
  // remove selected from siblings, toggle current selected class
  $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected').end().toggleClass('selected');
  var $target = $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id'));
  if ($target.length) {
    // hide any steps after the current one that may be shown
    $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('.step').not($target).removeClass('active');
    // toggle display of selected step
    $target.toggleClass('active'); 
  } else {
    console.log('do something else to end this thing');
  }
})
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/superladremi/979aL2g5/) is my JSFiddle inlcuding example and the code above.

Could I get a example of how the code will look with the code I already have, and a tiny explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little better? I can't seem to grasp what the problem is.

Comment: @ChadFisher I can try, sorry. The issue is in the last step of my JSFiddle (the green content), if you already selected McDonalds, try to select one of the other. [here](http://i.imgur.com/8kF1DP9.gifv) is a gif. When you select something else the content still toggles even though its selected and the target is still the same *(dataid="same_target")*, and this is what I would like to fix, if the target is the same, do not toggle.

Comment: replace `toggleClass` with  `addClass` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/979aL2g5/2/) ... or another solution [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/979aL2g5/3/)

Comment: @RolandStarke your last [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/979aL2g5/3/) was exactly what I've been hoping for. Thanks for taking your time helping me <3

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pointer-events: none;` for `.selected` class

```js
$('li').on('click',function(e) {
  
 if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
  return false;
 } else {
  e.preventDefault();
  // remove selected class from links after the current one
  $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('li').removeClass('selected');
  // remove selected from siblings, toggle current selected class
  $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected').end().addClass('selected');
  var $target = $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id'));
  if ($target.length) {
   // hide any steps after the current one that may be shown
   $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('.step').not($target).removeClass('active');
   // toggle display of selected step
   $target.addClass('active'); 
  } else {
   console.log('do something else to end this thing');
  }
 }
})
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.step {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.selected {
  background: #27ae60 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
ul {
  padding:0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.bananas {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.hi {
  color: #e74c3c;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #e74c3c;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#same_target {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #9b59b6;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#same_target p {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h1>First step, please choose something</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="one">
          Sprite
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="two">
          King Kong
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="three">
          Astronauts
        </li>
      </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="one" class="step">
    <h1>Second step for <span class="hi">Sprite</span> - choose another</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          McDonalds
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          Burger King
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          Tim Hortons
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="step">
      <h1>Second step for <span class="hi">King Kong</span> - choose another</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          McDonalds
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          Burger King
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          Tim Hortons
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="three" class="step">
      <h1>Second step for <span class="hi">Astronauts</span> - choose another</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          McDonalds
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          Burger King
        </li>
        <li class="bananas" data-id="same_target">
          Tim Hortons
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="same_target" class="step">
      <p class="fml">
        Now select another brand and watch this content toggle, even when the target is the same.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: That might be something that will come in handy, not quite what I was looking for although, but thanks. I dont want to deny toggling, I would rather prefer if a li with *data-id=* has the same target and one li is already selected, it wont toggle the content if you click on another li with the same *data-id=*. I might have explained my problem poorly.

Comment: @superladremi I've updated my post, you can add `if($(this).hasClass('selected')){return false;}else{//your code as it is}`